# Dividing a value and adding it to other rows using dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I wrote this code that does is the following.

In the table `mo102` there are costs that I want to divide and add equally to the rows of the table `table_reduced` that share the same values on some particular columns. Those columns are `id_s`, `t_hab`, `p_d`.

The problem is that using a for loop is not optimal and takes a lot of time. Is there a solution using `dplyr` to do this?

```
tblsin = as.data.frame(0, col.names = colnames(table_reduced))
lsin = length(mo102[[1]])
for (i in 1:lsin) {
  ns <- mo102[[3]][i]
  t_hab <- mo102[[4]][i]
  p_d <- mo102[[5]][i]
  cout_s <- mo102[[6]][i]

  temp <- table_reduced %>% filter(., ID_S %in% ns & T_HAB %in% t_hab & P_D %in% p_d & code_b != "MO102") 
  len <- length(temp[[1]])

  if (len != 0) {
    temp <- mutate(temp, total_cost = total_cost + cout_s/len)
    tblsin = bind_rows(tblsin, temp)
  }

}
```

A `mo102` table looks like this:

```
   piece.agr  DS_ESTETICO_PARTIDA           ID_SINIESTRO TIPO_HAB_D DS_PARTE_D total_cost
3       ASE            Directos 100210#000000986776904#2        ASE    _DIVERS        160
```

`table_reduced` looks like this:

```
              ID_SINIESTRO piece.agr          TIPO_HAB_D          DS_PARTE_D DS_ESTETICO_PARTIDA code_bareme total_cost
                     <chr>     <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>
2 100210#000000331493904#2       COC                 ASE             _DIVERS           Esteticos        P003     264.60

5 100210#000000986776904#2       ASE                 ASE             _DIVERS            Directos       PB101      94.20
```

The result I want is a `table_reduced` where the data from `total_cost` from the table `mo102` is divided by two and added to each of the rows, since they have the same attributes.

Since 160 is the cost on  `mo120`, it is divided by 2 (number of identical rows) and added to these rows.

So like this:

```
              ID_SINIESTRO piece.agr          TIPO_HAB_D          DS_PARTE_D DS_ESTETICO_PARTIDA code_bareme total_cost
                     <chr>     <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>
2 100210#000000331493904#2       COC                 ASE             _DIVERS           Esteticos        P003     344.60

5 100210#000000986776904#2       ASE                 ASE             _DIVERS            Directos       PB101      174.20
```

Comment: Pls [provide sample input data and expected outcome.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1261281)

Comment: @GGamba I edited the post.

Comment: I don't understand why is my question is downvoted ! I genuinely put effort into posting my questions on this website. If it's downvoted the reason must be at least mentioned !